# Error with simple UI script

Tags: pymel

I have this error message: # Error: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level #

I have tried to delete all indentations and replace the, with four spaces for each indentation, but I still get this error.

What should I do about this?

```py
import pymel.core as pm
class UI():
    def __init__(self):
        print 'init'


    def renameselection (self):
        sel=pm.ls(sl=True)
        dialog = pm.promptDialog(title='Rename Object',message='Enter Name:', button=['OK', 'Add','Cancel'],defaultButton='OK',cancelButton='Cancel',dismissString='Cancel')

        if dialog == 'OK':
            name = pm.promptDialog(query=True, text=True)
            for e in sel :
                e.rename(name)

        if dialog == 'Add':
            name = pm.promptDialog(query=True, text=True)
            for e in sel:
                e.rename(e+name)

     def CreateCircularController(self):

        dialog = pm.promptDialog(title='Name',message='Name CTL:', button=['OK','_CTL','Cancel'],defaultButton='OK',cancelButton='Cancel',dismissString='Cancel')
        selectedJoint=pm.ls(sl=True)
        name = pm.promptDialog(query=True, text=True)
        for e in selectedJoint:
            if dialog=='OK':
                Controller=pm.circle(nr=(0,1,0),n=name)
                ControllerGrp=pm.group(Controller,n=name)
            if dialog=='_CTL':
                Controller=pm.circle(nr=(0,1,0),n=name+'CTL')
                ControllerGrp=pm.group(Controller,n=name+'CTL')
            pm.parent(ControllerGrp,selectedJoint,r=1)
            pm.parent(ControllerGrp,w=1)



    def buttonfunction(self,*args):    
        print ('Rename')
        renameselection()  

    def secondButtonfunction(self,*args):
        print ('Create Controller')
        CreateCircularController()   

    ####### Layout
    def uipopup(self):
        mrwindow = pm.window( title="Bjorn_rigging_wizzard", iconName='BWZ', widthHeight=(200, 400) )        

        # if set to true adjustable column will automatically update the UI layout if the user rezizes the window.
        pm.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )

        # text in the menu
        pm.text(label='Select function doctor...')
        # layout of the menu, collums are downward and rows are horizontally made side by side   
        pm.columnLayout (columnAttach=('both', 5), rowSpacing=10, columnWidth=(100))
        # buttons are made into variables so that they can be called upon later with the setCommand - which enables functionallity
        buttonOne = pm.button(label='Rename', width=100, command=self.buttonfunction)
        buttonTwo = pm.button(label='Controller on selection', width=100)
        buttonTwo.setCommand(self.secondButtonfunction)

        # the setParent with '..' goes one back in hierachey, you will see the following text being outside of the "div" of the buttons.
        pm.setParent('..')
        pm.text(' ')
        pm.text('Blaabjergb.com')



        # once everything is build we can show the window
        pm.showWindow( mrwindow )

UI1=UI() 
UI1.uipopup()
```

Comment: The error should also contain a line number.

Comment: Variables shouldn't really be named with a capital letter, this isn't your problem here, however it should really be reserved for classnames not variables, camel case is fine but it's bad practice to do what you have done `ControllerGrp`

Answer (score 0):

1. Just noticed that there are 5 spaces before `def CreateCircularController`, and 4 spaces before the other method definition. Please make sure that each method definition has 4 spaces in front of it.
2. An error can also crop up due to the empty line right after `def CreateCircularController(self):`. Please delete the empty line and try again.

Comment: Hi Sunny, that does not seem to solve the error message. But creating a definition outside my class and caling upon that in the functionality seems to work. Maybe I just cant define functionality inside a class defining the UI.

Comment: @Bjørn Edited the answer with another observation. Please try that and let know if it works.